# Free Timeline Visualization API for Java?

Tags: java, visualization

Since days I'm looking for a Java visualization API that allows me to draw timelines [like this](http://timeline.verite.co/):

[image]

There seem to be a lot of JavaScript frameworks, but I can't find a Java implementation. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be interesting,
Fractalsoft.net has an extension for the primefaces framework that implements a timeline similar to what you descrive there.

Timeline:

http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/timeline/basicUsage.jsf

Also have a look at the rest of primefaces showcase, there are lots of cool gadgets:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf

I hope this is useful.